# Border on an Image-Button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a dynamic grid with buttons that act like images. For design purposes I want to be able to have a border around those pictures.

So here is the code:

```
EmployeeButton employeeTile = new EmployeeButton(); // inherits from Button, nothing fancy, just added three attributes for future use
Style style = this.FindResource("NoChromeButton") as Style;
employeeTile.Style = style;

// make it square (like a tile)
employeeTile.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.tileWidthInPx;
employeeTile.Height = employeeTile.Width;

// Create Background
var brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = item.Source; // item is an Image (part of a foreach)
employeeTile.Background = brush;

// set the margin between tiles
int margin = Properties.Settings.Default.tileMargin;
employeeTile.Margin = new Thickness(margin, margin, margin, 0);

// draw a border if the user wants to
if (Properties.Settings.Default.tileBorderThickness > 0)
{
    employeeTile.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
    employeeTile.BorderThickness = new Thickness(Properties.Settings.Default.tileBorderThickness);
}
```

For readability I deleted some lines that aren't involved with my question.

Here is the xaml code for the style that I use above. I found it somewhere on stackoverflow I think.:

```
<Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="0.5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

No matter how big I set the Thickness, there is no Border at all, just the clickable Image.

Comment: Does your button have a border attribute? Otherwise you'll want to create a border element, set the size/shape of that and nest the image/button inside that border element.

Comment: The only attributes I see is BorderBrush and BorderThickness, thats why I tried to set them.

Since I dynamically create these buttons, I first have to create the border and then add the button as a child? 

Something like (short):
border border = new border();
border.children.add(button); 

?

@CalebB

Comment: Yeah those are both "Border" attributes so it does have a border. Where is the border brush set? You may have to nest the button/image inside it's own border element: `<border "attributes">"stuff inside border"</border>`

Comment: I can only use code behind, since those Buttons have to be dynamically created. The XAML solution would be easy, but I can't do that. The current logic looks like the border is created but not visible, because the image is in an upper layer. I thought of creating the border and increasing the margin on the image, so that they don't overlap. I don't like that workaround that much.


In c# I just created the border, and added the image as a Child, but still only the Image is visible. That underlines my assumption regarding the overlapping of image and border. @CalebB

Comment: `I have a dynamic grid with buttons that act like images` - delete all that horrible code and use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Thank you for the nice words. Anyways, can I define a Clicked event for each item in the Items Control? @HighCore

Comment: @zuckerthoben you can do anything with an ItemsControl, everything that you're doing in code behind can be done in a proper way using proper XAML and databinding. Also, If you're doing a bunch of buttons your viewmodel is going to be an `ObservableCollection<ICommand>` and you bind the `Command` property of these buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ControlTemplate should look like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="0.5"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When you set the BorderBrush and BorderThickness in your code it will set the component's BorderBrush  and BorderThickness  but in your Template you don't use those properties so they won't be used. You just need to add a border using those properties in your ControlTemplate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. I just did that and it works. :) 

Have a nice day